# GraphQL Java with Spring boot Vs Apollo Server

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js, graphql-java

Both seems to be easy in terms of support and coding learning curve. But wondering about performance benefits?
Since Java Graphql with Spring boot will be JVM based solution, would there be any performance benefit?

PS I am new to Node.js and familiar with Java and Spring boot.